# How to find the cell next to active cell in excel

Tags: excel-2002

I want to create a log file in excel.

I have created a macro that will insert in-time into active cell on ButtonInTime click. Similarly out time in the active cell on ButtonOutTime click...

Now i want to insert todays date on **ButtonInTime click in previous cell of active cell**

and 
**calculate Total Log hours & insert it into next active cell of OutTime**.

How i can achive this?
Can any one help me out???

I tried to find out the solution, but didnt get the proper one...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: activecell.offset() will help to navigate cells in excel....

Answer (score 3):

I achieved it.. There are some hard codes in this....

```
Sub ButtonInTime_Click()
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select

activecell.Offset(1, 0).Select
activecell.Value = Date
activecell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Time()
activecell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
activecell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Log Not Closed!!!"


Range("A" & activecell.Row & ":E" & activecell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("A" & activecell.Row & ":E" & activecell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("A" & activecell.Row & ":E" & activecell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("A" & activecell.Row & ":E" & activecell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous

Range("B" & activecell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("C" & activecell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("D" & activecell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("E" & activecell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous

End Sub


Sub ButtonOutTime_Click()
Range("C1").End(xlDown).Select
activecell.Offset(1, 0).Select

activecell.Value = Time()
activecell.Offset(0, 1).Value = activecell.Value - activecell.Offset(0, -1).Value
activecell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)


End Sub
```